# angular2 Uncaught SyntaxError when accessing through dns and https

Tags: javascript, angular, networking, typescript, angular-cli

I have no idea why this problem happens. the site is written in angular2 typescript, and compiling with angular-cli.

when I upload the compiled app to the remote server and accessing the site through **static IP** or **DNS without https** all works fine. but when I try to access through the **DNS and https** which points to the same IP I get a screen with: "loading.." and in the console:
**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"** - authentication.service.ts:29 but the service is totally fine.

## the app is live at:

https://etype-solutions.com/ or https://81.199.117.250/

## versions:

```
os: ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Windows 10 x64
browser: chrome v55
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
node: 6.9.4
npm: 3.10.10
typescript: 2.0.10
angular2: 2.3.1
```

Comment: You must provide information about the error, where it occur, which error, which browser, what you mean by DNS... it is impossible to help you with the info you provided....

Comment: @vinagreti I accidently posted mid editing

Comment: It is redirecting to HTTPS version and the error are saying that it is trying to load HTTP (non secure) resources and that is blocked by the browser due to security issues. I think the problem I'm seeing is not the one you need help. Am I right? Can you disable the HTTPS redirection so I can see the real problem?

Comment: Also, there are a problem trying to connect to the websocket that is responsable for reloading the page when needed. Try to build your app as: `ng build --prod --aot`. The AOT option will compile your code at build and output the errors and you an fix it before deploy.

Comment: So I will put it as answer and ask you to vote as the correct one. Please.

Comment: @vinagreti it didn't help, I updated the question. I'm not loading HTTP and still doesn't work in https

Answer (score 0):

It is redirecting to HTTPS version and the error are saying that it is trying to load HTTP (non secure) resources and that is blocked by the browser due to security issues.

Use `//mylink.com` instead `http://mylink.com` or `https://mylink.com` so you will use the  current protocol and avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: i was wrong i get the same error. but i think i does have a connection to https